# Can't find CreateWithDisposable<T>()

Tags: winforms, system.reactive

I'm using Rx Framework version 1.0.10621 (Rx-Main and Rx-WinForms) installed over nuget within an Windows forms application and I can't find the method `CreateWithDisposable<T>()`!

Where is it? Which namespace or dll?

Comment: It is specific for the Windows Phone version, Microsoft.Phone.Reactive assembly.

Comment: I think it's an overload of Observable.Create now.

Comment: You mean, this one: `public static IObservable<TSource> Create<TSource>(Func<IObserver<TSource>, IDisposable> subscribe);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was removed as part of the "christmas" release.

The same functionality is available in the Create() overloads